# How to redirect index.php to a subfolder's file w/wo using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My directory looks like:

```
app
  |---- index.php
  |
  |---- Views
          |---- home.php
          |---- include.php
```

I want user to get redirected to `home.php` whenever they come to `app` directory and still want to show the url as `www.example.com/app`.
Also, is this possible to accomplish this with just php without having to touch `.htaccess` file. I would like to distribute the app on different servers. Can the `.htaccess` be located within the `app` directory ?

Comment: You could make app/index.php check the request then include the appropriate page right there.

Comment: in index.php use `<?php include('Views/home.php'); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

With htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app/?$ /app/Views/home.php [L]
```

---

With PHP:

Put the following as `app/index.php`:

```
<?php
    include( "Views/home.php" );
?>
```

Comment: Can the htaccess file be inside app directory ?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire Yes. But the server should process htaccess inside sub directories.

Comment: Thanks brother. Let me try it

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+.php)$ Views/$1
```

This will essentially send `/whatever.php` to `/Views/whatever.php`. Hope this helps someone.